# CORS problems on HEROKU

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

I have problem with CORS on Heroku.

**This is my code on server**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
require('dotenv').config()

import filmRoutes from './api/routes/films'
import userRoutes from './api/routes/users'

const app = express()

const DBNAME = process.env.DB_USER 
const DBPASSWORD = process.env.DB_PASS


mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${DBNAME}:${DBPASSWORD}@ds157422.mlab.com:57422/filmbase`, {useNewUrlParser: true})

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
  next();
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/films', filmRoutes)
app.use('/users', userRoutes)


export default app;
```

**This is my post request**

```
  CheckLogin = () => {
    const data = {
      name: this.state.formInput.login.value,
      password: this.state.formInput.password.value
    }
    axios.post('https://whispering-shore-72195.herokuapp.com/users/login', data)
    .then(response=>{
      console.log(response);
      const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + response.data.expiresIn * 1000)
      localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token)
      localStorage.setItem('expirationDate', expirationDate)
      this.context.loginHandler()
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err)
    })

    console.log(data);
  }
```

**This is ERROR**

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://whispering-shore-72195.herokuapp.com/users/login' from origin
>   'https://mighty-citadel-71298.herokuapp.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource.

I tried a lot of methods and nothing... any idea?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response. (Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check.)

Comment: Status Code: 503 Service Unavailable

Comment: So yeah then you don’t have CORS problem — instead you have a 503 Service Unavailable problem (the cause of which is unrelated to your CORS configuration)

Comment: so what is a problem? when i put a wrong values the status is 404

Answer (score 13):

You've cross origin domain on https://whispering-shore-72195.herokuapp.com from origin https://mighty-citadel-71298.herokuapp.com

You can try [npm cors package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) as middleware instead of your custom middleware. `CORS` package allows you multiple configure and it's very easy to use.

**Simple Usage (Enable All CORS Requests)**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';
require('dotenv').config()

import filmRoutes from './api/routes/films'
import userRoutes from './api/routes/users'

const app = express()

const DBNAME = process.env.DB_USER 
const DBPASSWORD = process.env.DB_PASS


mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${DBNAME}:${DBPASSWORD}@ds157422.mlab.com:57422/filmbase`, {useNewUrlParser: true})

/*app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
  next();
});*/

app.use(cors()); // <---- use cors middleware

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/films', filmRoutes)
app.use('/users', userRoutes)


export default app;
```

### Edit:

I've test your client call login to your server from `https` and it's working without CORS problem. Maybe you had fixed it successfully.

I've tried with simple on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-53876623?file=index.js) and it's working successfully.

You can try login https://js-53876623.stackblitz.io/ and view network tab when inspecting and see `OPTIONS (200 status)` and `POST (404 not found)` (because I don't know any user in your database)

### Edit Dec 22 2018 - 7:18 PM

I've tried your code on my local, maybe you hadn't tested and handled all error, it makes your app crash unfortunately.

I've run your code and noticed the problem maybe `jsonwebtoken` error:

> Error: secretOrPrivateKey must have a value

Please tried with `process.env.JWT_KEY || 'Require key here!!!',`, and set your `JWT_KEY` on your environment or use `||` as default key on server.

Maybe it will fix your problem.

### Recommends:

I have some recommends for your code:

- Please use `User.findOne()` instead of `User.find()`
- Please use `app.use(cors());`
- `jsonwebtoken` should use **Asynchronous** instead of Sync when run on server.

Comment: i tried cors package at the first time and still the same problem

Comment: I've test your client code with simple demo and it's working now. I've updated my answer

Comment: if you put a wrong values then status will be 404, but if you put a correct values then still is cors problem... ?

Comment: can you share an user and password for testing?

Comment: login: olosls
pass: tester

Comment: I think it's not a problem of CORS. Please check your code handling login, I think it has error, because 503 is server error, not related to CORS

Comment: i watching logs in heroku and, first time when the values is worng the logs throw staus 200 and then 404. but if i push wrong values in the logs i see, only status 503 and app crashed.

Comment: your handle incorrectly and it make app crash, please share your code

Comment: i shared, any feedback?

Comment: Yep, i forgot that .env is in .gitignore but i found another bug too, i had wrong export in userController.

Comment: I swear to god, I was missing the parens on `app.use(cors)`

Answer (score 9):

You need to determine if it is indeed a **CORS** issue or your API code is breaking.

If it's a **CORS** issue, handle **CORS** in your backend code like it's been suggested above or use the [`cors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package.

However, often times than not, the issue is that your code is breaking and you just didn't know. In my case, for instance, I didn't add `nodemon` to the dependencies and my `start` script is dependent on `nodemon` which Heroku could not find. So it's possible that your code works fine in dev but breaks in prod.

Here's how you can find what part of your code is breaking within Heroku:

1. Inspect your network in your browser dev tool. If the response is `503 Service Unavailable` as indicated below, that is an indication again that your code is  breaking.[image]
2. Locate the **More** button on the top right corner of your Heroku dashboard once you open the project you're having issues with.
   [image]
3. Select **View Logs** from the dropdown that shows up after you click the **More** button. You should now see the log of the track trace. If you don't see the error, try making any small change in your code and redeploying while watching the log again. In my case, as indicated below, the nodemon was the reason for the crash.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

I have deal with same problem, I think your problem is not CORS. Can you test your server logs. In my case i had a package problem and thats way i was getting 503 also No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header, CORS error. When i fix package and jwt problem my CORS problem solved!.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after deploying in Heroku, using console.log() in different points of the code, I could see an error message like this: 'RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded...'.
It was a NodeJs bug, I fixed it by adding this code at the bottom of my package.json:

"resolutions": {
"fs-capacitor": "3.0.0"
}

let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same cross error but
In my case what i needed was simply making sure the backend server (on Heroku) was running fine by viewing the logs from settings (on Heroku app setting) you can also check the logs via this command line heroku logs --tail

Answer (score 0):

I may be late, but it may be helpful to someone else.

I have faced the same issue in Heroku related to the CORS. I have tried all the combinations of origin and many other workarounds in cors.

But later I found that it is an issue in TypeScript compilation.

### Solution

In the `tsconfig.json` file, I have set `incremental` to `true`, which does not generate the js files that caused this issue.

So, for each request, Heroku sends 503 error messages.

### To analyse the error in Heroku

You can use the activity tab or logs from Heroku. Attached is the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is related to Service Unavailable from the CORS Heroku server. Since it is a free service, the number of calls per hour is limited to 50. Please try to use your own CORS server as a middleware as suggested in the answers or self host CORS-Anywhere

Answer (score -4):

I had a similar issue with Heroku and my backend, which was hosted in vercel in now.

If you are using environment variable make sure you set those in your vercel app, or if you're hosting anywhere else check that before anything else. ENV VARIABLES!

Comment: Wait... could you clarify your answer? the question has nothing to do with vercel, it's a CORS issue between two Heroku domains.

Comment: @germanio I was just sharing my findings with this issue. As I was researching I was coming across this post over and over again so I thought anyone coming across this same issue could benefit, but I should probably open up a new thread. The issue was with the environment variables. Also I found better luck hosting the Front End from Netlify since CORS was never an issue there, if you specified the request origin.