# can't get node api from heroku using axios on react app

Tags: reactjs, heroku, axios

after i deploy my node api successfully to heroku. i try to access my node api using heroku address like this https://something.herokuapp.com/somefilter. i'm using chrome and postman and it is working. it returning json object

but when i try to get it from my react app on localhost using axios it is not working and result in error 'Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined'

this is my react code that result in error

```
async function getResults() {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`https://something.herokuapp.com/somefilter`);
            dispatch({
                type: 'GET_TRANSACTIONS',
                payload: res.data.data
            });
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: 'TRANSACTION_ERROR',
                payload: err.response.data.error
            });
        }
    }
```

but if i run this react code for my node api on localhost:5000 it is running fine and produce json object

```
async function getResults() {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`/somefilter`);
            dispatch({
                type: 'GET_TRANSACTIONS',
                payload: res.data.data
            });
        } catch (err) {
            dispatch({
                type: 'TRANSACTION_ERROR',
                payload: err.response.data.error
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem is solved. after searching i figured it out the problem is with cors. i try solution from this post
[CORS problems on HEROKU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53875548/cors-problems-on-heroku) and it works

add this 2 line to my server.js just for simple usage

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors());
```